# Объединить и удалить записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, с полями: `id | stid | name | price`. Как лучше в запросе объединить записи с одинаковыми stid, в price записать их сумму, и оставить только одну из этих записей?

Comment: Просто по порядку (в любом случае будет 3 запроса, можно сделать 2, но один будет все равно с еще одним вложенным):

1. Проссумировать все с одним stid

2. Удалить все с одним stid

3. Вставить новую строку

Comment: Если просто выборку, то

     select id, stid, name, sum(price) from t group by stid;

Если нужно обновить исходную страницу, то чуть сложнее. Возможны разные варианты, но желательно получить доп. сведения о таблице. Напр. id -- уникальна или нет?

Comment: @alexlz исходную страницу нужно обновить, id уникальное.

На данный момент подумываю делать несколько запросов (в одном обновлять данные, в другом удалять).

Comment: я б на вашем месте сделал бы дополнительное булин поле: упаковано/не упаковано. регулярно выполняем следующее действие: 1) выбираем все айдишники записей у которых флаг = не упаковано. 2) для них делаем аггрегацию и вставляем новую строчку с типом упаковано. 3) потом по айдишникам удаляем записи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще и безопаснее всего - будет делать в два этапа.

1.

Создаёте точно такую же (по структуре) таблицу с движком MEMORY (если мучает сильное беспокойство, сделайте на стандартном движке, чтоб сохранилась на диске).

Сделайте что-то типа

```
INSERT INTO MEMORY_TABLE(stid, name, price) select stid, name, max(price) from oldTabel group by stid, name
```

Если для одного stid, name может быть несколько, тогдa name выбирается вложенным запросом такое, какое вам нужно (group by будет только по stid).

2.

На данном этапе у вас есть возможность полностью проверить корректность данных.

Удаляете все записи из старой таблицы.

Аналогичным запросом перегоняете из memory в старую таблицу.

Дропаете memory-таблицу.

P.S. Само-собой, для регулярных автоматизированных операций это не очень подходит, но для одноразовых ручных переделок очень хорошо себя зарекомендовало. Особенно, когда таблицы сложнее - чем у вас сейчас.

P.P.S. Делать лучше, когда в БД не шарятся пользователи. И не забыть сделать бакап, до того как делать))

Comment: проблема в том, что это автоматизированное дествие,выполняется регулярно.

Comment: Если такое, нужно делать регулярно, то есть ошибки в архитектуре БД.

Возможно, вам нужна ещё одна, итоговая таблица, где вы будете хранить данные в разрезе stid, price. Обновлять триггерами например.

И вопрос, почему нельзя использовать sum(price)+group by stid в select-запросах?

Comment: Если есть окно в обслуживании пользователей, то проблем быть не должно. По cron'у запускайте скрипт.

Comment: Ваша таблица, это вообще что - позиции заказов или отгрузки? Бо что-то плохо придумывается, где бы ещё нужно было суммировать цены.

Comment: @SilverIce

      И вопрос, почему нельзя использовать sum(price)+group by stid в select-запросах?

Как нельзя? (А в mysql можно даже и брать поля, не участвующие в group без групповых функций: max, sum и т.д. Хотя это, конечно, изврат)

Comment: @alexlz Я не про SQL-спрашивал. Я спрашивал, почему не используют.

Comment: @alexlz действие выполняется по действию от пользователя, крона не надо )
@SilverIce это таблица заказов, stid - объект какой заказывали (p.s. я выписал только часть таблицы, на самом деле там больше колонок). Логика таблицы следующая - персонал может заказать канцтовар. При этом могут появиться дубликаты канцтоваров с различными написаниями, например "Ручка", "Ручка синяя", для таких случаев у менеджера есть возможность объеденить несколько видов канцтоваров объеденить в один, при этом у сотрудников, заказавшего 2 "Ручки" и 5 "Ручка синяя" после объединения должно получиться 8 "Ручка".

Comment: До меня уже потом дошло.

У вас самое просто банальное интерактивное редактирование (в данном случае объединением). 

По нажатию клиента, РНР (ну или на чем у вас написано) запрашивает обе стоки. На себе их суммирует. Обновляет ту, что остается. Если прошло успешно - удаляет вторую - всё.

После объединения должно получится 7)